# SEO meta tags are showing in page source but cannot preview them

Tags: next.js, meta-tags

In my Next.js app I'm trying to insert `og meta tags` with dynamic content on a product page. So the content of the `meta tags` will change based on the product data fetched from server.

I am fetching product data using `getServerSideProps` and passing product data to page component as `props`.

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    store => async (context) => {

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
        });
        const data = await response.json();

        return {
            props: {
                host: context.req.headers.host,
                product: data.product
            }
        }
    }
)
```

**First Approach**

I tried to insert `meta tags` directly on my product page component within `<Head>` component. Here `meta tags` even with static conetnt are not showing in page source.

```
const Product = ({product}) => {
    return (
        product ?
            <>
                <Head>
                    <title>{product.title}</title>
                    <meta name="description"
                          content={product.description}/>
                    <meta property="og:title" content={product.title}/>
                    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
                    <meta property="og:url" content={`${props.host}/products/${product.slug}`}/>
                    <meta property="og:description" content={product.description}/>
                    <meta property="og:image" content={product.thumbnail}/>
                </Head>
                <Course/>
            </> : null
    );
};
```

**Second Approach**

```
return (
    <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
            {/*<meta property="og:image" content="https://static.onlinevideobooks.com/abed1e5658b3ad23c38c22646968e4f2/files/media/images/2022/04/5b0645b9-ab03-4233-b5f3-86b092d4062b/conversions/cad47d2beb9143eab3d65ea4a75b0b0e-1280x720.webp" />*/}

            {/*<title>your keyword rich title of the website and/or webpage</title>*/}
            <meta name="description"
                  content="description of your website/webpage, make sure you use keywords!"/>
            <meta property="og:title" content="short title of your website/webpage"/>
            <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
            <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/"/>
            <meta property="og:description" content="description of your website/webpage"/>
            <meta property="og:image"
                  content="https://example.com/image"/>
        </Head>
    </Html>
);
```

I tried inserting `meta tags` within `<Head>` in `_document.js` file. Here I am passing only static conetnt as I don't have dynamic data in `_document.js`. This time `meta tags` are showing up in page source and I can also preview them on facebook.

**Third Approach**

Then I try to insert those tag in `_app.js` file as I receive `pageProps` in this component.
Unfortunately when I pass dynamic content in `meta tags` like first approach, they do not show up in page source but they do when I pass static conetnt similar to second approach.

[full _app.js code gist](https://gist.github.com/skfahad/bbc5cd609982d425434e227f20eec5f6)

**UPDATE**

As regard to my third approach, I checked once again and surprisingly I can see all `meta tags` in page source when inserted either with static or dynamic content in `_app.js`. I can preview the url when content is static but when content is dynamic I can not preview the url using either [Facebook debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) or [Open graph](https://www.opengraph.xyz/)

*My Next.js version is 12.2.0*

Comment: Do you have any conditional rendering or anything like that or are you setting the meta tags on the client? Or do you have a `useEffect` call with an empty dependency array that is conditionally rendering your page based on state?

If your meta tags aren't there when you "View page source" in the browser, then that means your meta tags aren't ready yet because there is something happening in the client that is "blocking" them.

Comment: Yes, I have a conditional rendering in `_app.js` that waits for data to be available from the API that is being called after the page is loaded. But I even tried to put `meta tags` before the conditional statement as mentioned in **third approach**. I have updated question with code from `_app.js` file

Comment: Can you please show us your full `_app` page code?

Comment: Sure, I have added `_app.js` in gist [here](https://gist.github.com/skfahad/bbc5cd609982d425434e227f20eec5f6) and updated the question as well

Comment: In regards to having the metatags in the `Product` page, the `SafeHydrate` is forcing your pages to render on the client-side only, causing the HTML (including the metatags) not to be present in the page source.

Comment: However, the metatags in `_app` should be rendered properly on the server as they sit outside `SafeHydrate`. If you log `pageProps?.product?.thumbnail` on the server-side, what do you get?

Comment: Actually I checked once again and surprisingly I can see all `meta tags` in page source when inserted in `_app.js`. But still I can not preview the url using either [facebook debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) or [open graph](https://www.opengraph.xyz/)

Comment: On [Facebook debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I get the warning `The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.`

Comment: If you can see the `og:image` metatag on the page source then it may be a caching issue with Facebook Sharing debugger. Try invalidating the cache for that URL.

Comment: Yes I do invalidate the cache everytime I update my code using `scrap again` button and I am sure caches are being cleared everytime

Comment: So I got the problem, my API call that fetches product data was inside a condition that checks if `access_token` is available in cookie and obviously [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) cannot send `access_token` when requesting `og:url`. So my **third approach** is working with dynamic content as well. It was a silly mistake from my end

Comment: I've spent 3 hours today trying to figure out why my SEO tags are not showing up in view-source using next.js and it turned out that I was using a hook `useFontFaceObserver` in `_app` to wait for font load before rendering the page to avoid FOUT (Flash of Unstyled Text) which prevented next.js `Head` tag on the page from ssr. Removing this hook fixed the issue and my tags are now showing in view-source.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the code you have in your `_app.js` is blocking the meta tags from being rendered. The "View page source" in browsers will not wait for client code to finish rendering. You can verify this and click "View page source" from your browser. Do you see any of the HTML you are expecting, for example do you see your meta tags and product html?

I expect that you probably don't see anything except some static HTML tags. One thing you could try is moving your use of hooks and rendering logic down into its own `MainLayout` component.

You can then try your **first approach** where you do something like this:

```jsx
const Product = ({product}) => {
    return (
        product ?
            <>
                <Head>
                    <title>{product.title}</title>
                    <meta name="description"
                          content={product.description}/>
                    <meta property="og:title" content={product.title}/>
                    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
                    <meta property="og:url" content={`${props.host}/products/${product.slug}`}/>
                    <meta property="og:description" content={product.description}/>
                    <meta property="og:image" content={product.thumbnail}/>
                </Head>
                <MainLayout>
                    <Course/>
                <MainLayout>
            </> : null
    );
};
```

Where `MainLayout` contains all the logic you have in your `_app.js`. This should keep your actual `_app.js` free of any client side code that is blocking the meta tags from rendering.

Basically we want to utitlize Next.js static optimization and have it pre-render the meta tags for your page so that the browser and web crawlers get the data without having to wait for any client side rendering.

Comment: Actually I checked once again and surprisingly I can see all `meta tags` in page source when inserted in `_app.js`. But still I can not preview the url using either [facebook debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) or [open graph](https://www.opengraph.xyz/)

Comment: Right, but how are you viewing the page source? Through the dev tools or do you right click the page and click "View page source". Dynamic content won't show up if you are using the client to render it which is why the facebook debug isn't able to see the meta tags

Comment: I right click the page and click "View page source". Right now I can see all `meta tags` in page source even with dynamic content. But I cannot preview them using either [Facebook debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) or [Open graph](https://www.opengraph.xyz/)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this helps someone, but my issue was the placement of the `<Head>` tags within `_app.js`.  For some reason, when it was nested under `<Auth0ProviderWithHistory>` the meta tags would not render, moving it outside of this gave me victory.

Broken

```
<Auth0ProviderWithHistory>    
<Head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            
            {openGraphData.map((og) => (
                <meta {...og} />                
            ))}

            <title>{pageProps.title}</title>

        </Head>    
        <CssBaseline>            
                <div className="page-layout">                                         
                    <NavBar />     
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                    <Footer />                
                </div>
        </CssBaseline>
    </Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
```

Fixed

```
<span>
        <Head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            
            {openGraphData.map((og) => (
                <meta {...og} />                
            ))}

            <title>{pageProps.title}</title>


        </Head>
    <Auth0ProviderWithHistory>        
        <CssBaseline>            
                <div className="page-layout">                                         
                    <NavBar />     
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                    <Footer />                
                </div>
        </CssBaseline>
    </Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going under the hood, but removing the `Head` tag resolves this for me.

I just put my meta tags without nesting them inside `Head`, and it worked.